# Diff two folders with different sub-directory structures

Tags: windows-7, sync

I have two folders with different hierarchies. One is flat and the other is sorted by date(folders for month and sub-folders for date). I'd like to either flatten the hierarchy, create the hierarchy, or just have a program that can sync with the hierarchy difference.

I'm on Windows 7, but I have cygwin if there is a commandline diff I can run.

These are just pictures and movies. I have renamed the files in both directories according to the date taken, so I think I can just compare file names and don't need to care about file contents. Does this make this easier? Perhaps I can just list all files and then diff the two logs.

Comment: You can look into rsync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been a while now since I came up with a solution, but I will try to recap it. I used `find . -name '*'` to get a list of all the files in both structures and piped it into two text files. I manually went in to the text file for the hierarchical structure and removed the folder names using regex find-replace on `.*/\.*/\` in notepad++. Lastly, I removed any directories manually that were not done with the regex. Then I did a `diff` on the two log files to find the files that were not in both structures.

Answer (score 1):

I feel sure that you could solve this problem with PowerShell or other scripting languages.

```
Get-ChildItem - Lists files. 
New Item - Creates folders
Copy-Item - Copy the files.
Compare-Object - Highlights differences.
```

P.S. Could you clarify if you want to create a permanent new structure, or to keep two existing structures synchronised.  If the later then I would incorporate Task Scheduler into the solution.

Comment: I'm going to synchronize the structures, but I haven't decided which one to keep.